# Debugging VMWare Workstation Guest Process

Tags: debugging, vmware

Im using Win8.1 x64 as host and I got a VM with Win7 x86.
Is it possible to debug a guest process from the host using IDA Pro or Ollydbg?
If yes, could you please give me some references/tips?

I appreciate any help.